# How to keep iframe session alive from parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I want the iframe's session to remain alive when there
is an activity on the parent page. The solution I was thinking
to ping an image url of iframe's domain from the parent page whenever 
there is some activity on the parent page. This is an ASP.Net application hosted on IIS 7.

My question is does pinging the iframe's domain from parent page
will update the iframe's session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by attaching a click handler on the parent's body and making a get request to any image on the child domain.